# Swift map on UILabel "Anonymous closure argument not contained in closure"

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, closures

Making three separate calls to `addSubview()` on `contentView` for an instance of `UITableViewCell` may be reduced to Swift `map(_:)`:

```
[nameLabel, numberLabel, informationLabel].map(contentView.addSubview($0))
```

The shorthand, however, throws an error: "Anonymous closure argument not contained in closure". Would `.forEach` be the best here?

Comment: whenever you use higher order functions like `map` you must **wrap** the what it does with a `{...}` so it should me `map{contentView.addSubView($0)}`

Comment: Thanks, @Honey! You helped me.

Comment: Why `map(_:)`? `addSubview(_:)` doesn't return anything. Sounds like you just want a simple loop.

Comment: @Hamish I agree. I realized that `.forEach` is the best after I remembered that `.map(_:)` returns a transformed `Array`, which is totally unnecessary for my purposes.

Comment: @Eric My comment is partially wrong, I'm sure you've seen the accepted answer. In addition to doing what I said you can also just pass a function (e.g. `contentView.addSubview`) and do something like: `map(contentView.addSubview)`

Comment: @Honey, I know but your comments were nonetheless helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is invalid because it's using an *anonymous closure argument* `$0`, without being in a closure.

```
[nameLabel, numberLabel, informationLabel].map(contentView.addSubview($0))
```

There are two ways to fix this, either put it in a closure:

```
[nameLabel, numberLabel, informationLabel].map { contentView.addSubview($0) }
```

Or better yet, just use the instance method directly:

```
[nameLabel, numberLabel, informationLabel].map(contentView.addSubview)
```

In either case, you should use `forEach` rather than `map`, since you don't care about the (`Void`) return value of `addSubview`:

```
 [nameLabel, numberLabel, informationLabel].forEach(contentView.addSubview)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .forEach when closure returns void

```
 [nameLabel, numberLabel, informationLabel].forEach { contentView.addSubview($0) }
```